# Why is the <packaging> element included

Tags: maven, nexus, pom.xml, maven-central

When I navigate to - http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.portals.pluto%7Cpluto-container-api%7C2.0.2%7Cbundle

the dependency is -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.portals.pluto</groupId>
    <artifactId>pluto-container-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
</dependency>
```

Should it not be -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.portals.pluto</groupId>
    <artifactId>pluto-container-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

As including the  tag seems to cause an error, attached -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a fair assumption that the XML you quote is intended to be copied and pasted into a pom.xml.

You're right. Removing `<packaging>` is the correct thing to do.

There's no need to specify the type, because the bundles artifacts have a 'jar' extension anyway.  Even if the packaging was not 'jar' ‒say, for example, it was 'war'‒ the correct element to use would be `<type>` and not `<packaging>`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that `<type>` is the correct element to be used in the `dependency` section and not `<packaging>` (which is suggested by the repository web interface)

Comment: Why should use <type> instead of <packaging> ? Is this to avoid confusion with the top level <packaging> element ?

Comment: @user470184 There is a top level `<packaging>` element which defines the project's artifact type. If you want to specify this in the `<dependency>` section you have to use the `<type>` element. That's just how the [pom structure](http://maven.apache.org/pom.htm) is defined. For both elements `jar` is the default.

Comment: @K. Claszen Pom link is broken, think should be ? maven.apache.org/pom.html

Comment: @user470184 You are right - the link is [http://maven.apache.org/pom.html](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html) - can't edit original comment any more.

Answer (score 2):

The artifact was build using the [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) to enable the artifact to be used in OSGi environments (can be seen in the parent pom of this bundle). This plugin introduces the '`bundle`' packaging type.

As the artifact is still a 'jar' you can skip specifying the `<type>` in your dependency section (The presented `<dependency>` section of the repository web interface you mentioned is wrong. There is no `<packaging>` element inside `<dependency>`. `<packaging>` is one of the maven [coordinates](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates)).